# How to compile a file as c++ in flex windows?

Tags: windows, lex

I am using "flex windows(lex & yacc)" in windows 7 32 bit, where the lex programs can be compiled, built and run by automatic call on command prompt, using some tools. But by default, it compiles files as c...which i want to change so as to compile as c++. is there any way to do that without using any cmd command?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that [flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)) is a C or C++ code generator. And so is [bison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Bison). They both *emit* some C++ (or C) code from some other kind of input.

So, **compile on the command line.** BTW, all C++ compilers I heard about are command line programs.

> is there any way to do that without using any cmd command?

In practice, code your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) to drive `flex`, `bison`, `g++` or `clang++` (or any other C++ command line compiler you have). Then you'll just build your program using `make` -and you could and probably should **configure your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) or [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-code_editor)** (e.g. [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), etc...) **to build your program** that way (maybe with a single mouse click or a single keypress).

Or use some other [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool. For example, [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/).

How to configure your IDE or editor is of course specific to that editor. I am using `emacs` (on Linux) and my `~/.emacs` configuration file contains:

```
(load-library "compile")
(global-set-key [f12] 'recompile)
```

So I simply compile by pressing the <kbd>F12</kbd> key. That fires a  `make` process.